# make a generic js file to be used across all views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, entity-framework-6

So there is a script I wrote in each view to show notification status according to a specific result. I want to make it in a single js file and then just call it in each view. the problem is `@TempData` can't be read in the js file or to be clear outside the `.cshtml` files. So what should I do to avoid this redundancy?

```
<script>

     $(function () {

     var msg = "@(TempData["error"] as string)";
        if (msg !== "") {

            toastr.error('@TempData["error"]');
            toastr.options = {

                "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right"

            }
        }

    });

     $(function(){
     var msg = "@(TempData["success"] as string)";
        if (msg !== "") {

            toastr.success('@TempData["success"]');
            toastr.options = {

                "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right"

            }
        }

    });

    $(function(){
     var msg = "@(TempData["warning"] as string)";
        if (msg !== "") {

            toastr.warning('@TempData["warning"]');
            toastr.options = {

                "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right"

            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create function in main .js file as below and call function by passing message and code from cshtml like below

```
 function showNotification(messageType, message){
    toastr.options = {
            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right"
        }
    if(messageType == 1)       //  warning
    {
        toastr.warning(message);            
    }
    else if(messageType == 2)   //  success
        toastr.success(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TempData is a dictionary type which is designed to be used in the subsequent request. You can retain TempData values in a third consecutive request by TempData.Keep()
 [image]

In your case TempData is not suitable. As you are using .NET MVC framework so you may write something in your common Layout page like below before Renderbody(). Pass your message with ViewBag and it will show to all pages as all view will extend common layout view.

```
  <div class="col-md-12 sidebar-offcanvas" id="bodyContent" role="navigation">
            <br />
            <div class="customMessage text-center">
                @if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                        <strong>Error!</strong> @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
                    </div>
                }

                @if (ViewBag.SuccessMessage != null)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                        <strong>Success!</strong> @ViewBag.SuccessMessage
                    </div>
                }

                @if (ViewBag.InfoMessage != null)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                        <strong>Info! </strong>@ViewBag.InfoMessage
                    </div>
                }

                @if (ViewBag.WarningMessage != null)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                        <strong>Warning! </strong>@ViewBag.WarningMessage
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
```